# How to create stitched material

Tags: materials, pbr

I have to  create an object with this material (see image). Unfortunately, I cannot find anything similar on the material sites I normally use. it's very specific with these red and black lines. Seems to be sewed/stiched or so.

Just wanted to ask for your opinions, how you would create/replicate this. Thank you for your ideas. Christoph

[image: material]

Comment: Might be interested in this https://gumroad.com/l/Knittr

Comment: It looks like denim/jeans fabric to me. You can create it procedural with wave texture nodes https://youtu.be/Y9-B7H9z1TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try something like this. It's really just a couple of Wave textures criss-crossed with each other (one at a slight angle). I perturbed the input vectors of the Wave textures slightly with a Noise Texture to better simulate "stray fibers" (similar effect to wave texture's "distortion" value but allows more control such as independently changeable scale to the noise). I used the mix as the basis for a Bump Map, the BaseColor mix factor, and some Ambient Occlusion that I ultimately mixed with the final color. Don't forget to enable Ambient Occlusion in the Render Properties settings. Lastly, I upped the roughness and lowered the specularity slightly.

[image: Fabric]

Comment: Man, this is just incredible. Thank you so much! Do you know some ressources on how to learn reverse engineer such materials? On yt i just found videos showing how to create certain materials step by step. But that doesnt really help me understand it and getting better at this kind of problem solving. Cheers c

Comment: This dude helped me a bunch along the way (Default Cube) - This video is _long_ (2 hours for part 1) but it explains pretty much _everything_ in a way that you get a very good understanding of what the nodes do and how procedural generation works. Maybe save it for a rainy night - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3gLBhC353Y - After that, you just have to get creative and practice different ways of making a bunch of crap. Some tactics will work better than others - the only way to know is to mess with it for a _while_.

Comment: Oh, forgot to add, feel free to watch (but not get intimidated by) the flashy examples at the beginning, then skip to the 35min mark, which is where the real "lessons" begin.

Comment: @Christoph if you want to get a bit further into the maths, maybe worth stepping outside Blender.. [Inigo Quilez](https://iquilezles.org/index.html) is a great source, as is [The Art of Code](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGmrMu-IwbgsVjE7SAtFaWyhZXyBjJNnO). That's GLSL, but the maths is the same. Check out what the shader-freaks get up to on [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/).